# NSMutableArray does not return value and assign to variable

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` in my code and I want to access the last element of that array and save the element in integer `n` variable.  But `n` does not give me the correct value when I `NSLog` it, it gives me a garbage value.

```
 for(int i=0;i<[array3 count];i++)
    {
        if(i==([array3 count]-1))
        {
            n = [array3 objectAtIndex:i];
        }    
    }

    NSLog(@"The id is=%d",n);

    NSError *error;
    NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *dataPath = [aDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",n]];
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: If n is type int, it would not work.  Because array only holds object and int is not object.

Comment: the n is type int but it give me the garbage value.

Comment: You can't store int in an NSMutableArray directly. Paste the code where you are adding objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays contain objects, not scalar types like ints.  Try this instead:

```
id n = [array3 lastObject];          // prettier than objectAtIndex:[array count]-1
NSLog(@"the last object is %@", n);   // %@ is an object format descriptor
```

Maybe the array contains NSNumbers that make sense as integers?  Then,

```
NSNumber *n = [array3 lastObject];
NSLog(@"the last object is %@ or view it this way %d", n, [n intValue]);
```

You can also access an array with newer syntax like this:

```
id n = array3[array3.count-1];
```

You can also iterate an array more quickly and concisely like this:

```
for (id object in array3) {
    NSLog(@"%@", object);
}
```

Comment: sir, what is "id" mean what is its type?

Comment: An id is an objective-c keyword that is 'some kind of object', see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

Comment: id is the objective c generic type, like void* in c.  You probably ought to figure out what type(s) is really contained by the array and code for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you a garbage value because you're trying to cast an object to a primitive most likely.

Also, that for loop is unnecessary.

`n = [[array3 lastObject] integerValue];`

Should be everything you need. If that is still garbage, it's because the object in your array is garbage (or can't be cast to an integer). At that point, take a look at where you're setting up array3.

Comment: Since OP uses `%d` in his `NSLog()` I assume he uses `int` and not `NSInteger`, so would call `intValue` instead of `integetValue` ;)